# Google api authorization raises the browser

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm writing a small desktop app that will upload file to google drive. So everything is fine when I'm sign in my google account, but when I'm not, program raises browser on this page "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin". I'm using this code:

```
        ClientSecrets secret = new ClientSecrets();
        secret.ClientId = "my_client_id";
        secret.ClientSecret = "my_client_secret";
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secret, new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result;

        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = "TestUpload" });

        File body = new File();
        body.Title = "Title123";
        body.Description = "Decription123";
        body.MimeType = "image/png";

        byte[] arr = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(arr);

        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "image/png");
        request.Upload();
```

So how can I authorize programmatically with out raising the browser?

Comment: You normally can't with OAuth, the entire point of the protocol is you never need to tell your password directly to applications that want to authenticate you. Usually if you do end up working around this restriction and you get discovered your app's API key will be revoked.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain So there is no way not to raise browser?

Answer (score 2):

Most of your problem is the fact that you are not saving the Authentication.  You are requesting access but not saving it.   In the following example fileDataStore stores the authentication information in a file on your pc in %AppData% this way next time you run the program no authentication will be needed, and it also wont require that you are logged into Google at the time.

```
//Scopes for use with the Google Drive API
string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                                 DriveService.Scope.DriveFile};
// here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
UserCredential credential = 
            GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
                          .AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = CLIENT_ID
                                                            , ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET }
                                          ,scopes
                                          ,Environment.UserName
                                          ,CancellationToken.None
                                          ,new FileDataStore("Daimto.GoogleDrive.Auth.Store")
                                          ).Result;
DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
 HttpClientInitializer = credential,
 ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
 });

 public static File uploadFile(DriveService _service, string _uploadFile, string _parent) {

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(_uploadFile))
            {
                File body = new File();
                body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_uploadFile);
                body.Description = "File uploaded by Diamto Drive Sample";
                body.MimeType = GetMimeType(_uploadFile);
                body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = _parent } };

                // File's content.
                byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_uploadFile);
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
                try
                {
                    FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _service.Files.Insert(body, stream, GetMimeType(_uploadFile));
                    request.Upload();
                    return request.ResponseBody;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("File does not exist: " + _uploadFile);
                return null;
            }           

        }
```

This code is ripped from the [Google Drive C# upload](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/) tutorial, if you want more information on what its doing and how it works you may want to check that.   There is also a working Sample project in the [Google-Dotnet-Samples](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Drive) project on GitHub.  The tutorial is based upon that sample project.